# Can I get a List of functions using filter in Python?

Tags: python, list, lambda

I have a list which has the divisors of 10 like this:

```
print filter(lambda x: 10 % x == 0, range(1, 10))
>>>[1, 2, 5]
```

Then I need a List of function like that :

```
F =  [lambda x:k+x for k in filter(lambda x: 10 % x == 0, range(1, 10))]
```

When I call every functions in the List, it turns out to be wrong:

```
for f in F:
   print(f(0))
>>> 5
>>> 5
>>> 5
```

so How can I get the right list of function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the lambda function captures the variable `k`. To get around it, you can copy it to a variable local to the lamba function:

```
F =  [lambda x, k=k:k+x for k in filter(lambda x: 10 % x == 0, range(1, 10))]
```

Comment: Further reading: [What do (lambda) function closures capture in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2295290/what-do-lambda-function-closures-capture-in-python)